# How do I iterate over a list of chars while still being able to skip in the iteration?

Tags: while-loop, rust, iteration, chars

I have the following piece of code:

```
let mut lex_index = 0;
let chars = expression.chars();
while lex_index < chars.count() {
    if(chars[lex_index] == "something") {
        lex_index += 2;
    } else {
        lex_index += 1;
    }
}
```

I use a `while` loop here since I sometimes need to skip a char in `chars`.
However, this gives me the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `chars`
  --> src/main.rs:23:15
   |
23 |     while i < chars.count() {
   |               ^^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `chars` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: `Chars<>` is an iterator, not a collection, so you can't index into it that way anyway.

Comment: Just use `continue` when you want to skip a char...

Comment: I have indeed noticed this, this is however a quick piece of code i came up with to illustrate the type of behavior i am looking for.

Answer (score 10):

It's better to iterate over something instead of using an index:

```
let mut chars = "gravy train".chars().fuse();

while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
    if c == 'x' {
        chars.next(); // Skip the next one
    }
}
```

We [`fuse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse) the iterator to avoid any issues with calling `next` after the first `None` is returned.

---

Your code has a number of issues:

1. [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) consumes the iterator. Once you've called that, the iterator is **gone**. That's the cause of your error. An alternate solution is to use [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) so that consuming the iterator you count isn't the end of the line.
2. `chars` is of type [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html), which does not support indexing. `chars[lex_index]` is nonsensical.
3. You cannot compare a `char` to a string, so `chars[lex_index] == "something"` wouldn't compile either. It's possible you could use [`Chars::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str), but then you'd have to give up `Fuse` and deal with that yourself.

Comment: Based on my interpretation of https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html, the Chars iterator is already fused. According to the documentation, calling fused() on an already fused operator has no effect and results no performance penalty. Was your use of ".fuse()" intentional? Maybe that aspect of the library has been updated since 15/07/17.

Comment: @hddh you've basically answered your own question: *calling `fused()` on an already fused operator has no effect and results no performance penalty*. Always call `fuse` when you need the ability to call `next` after the iterator returns `None` once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`strcursor`](https://docs.rs/strcursor/0.2.5/strcursor/index.html) crate for this:

```
extern crate strcursor;

fn main() {
    use strcursor::StrCursor;
    let expr = r"abc\xdef";
    let mut cur = StrCursor::new_at_start(expr);

    // `after`: the next grapheme cluster
    while let Some(gc) = cur.after() {
        if gc == "\\" {
            // Move right two grapheme clusters.
            cur.seek_next();
            cur.seek_next();
        } else {
            print!("{}", gc);
            cur.seek_next();
        }
    }
    println!("");
}

// Output: `abcdef`
```